# Windows Phone 7 Connect to SharePoint via SOAP

Tags: silverlight, soap, windows-phone-7

I am making my second application for the Windows 7 Phone Series platform and I cannot seem to connect to a SharePoint server using https.

99% of the following is not my code.  I have borrowed it from http://blog.daisley-harrison.com/blog/post/Practical-Silverlight-and-SharePoint-Integration-Part-Two.aspx untill I can further understand how SOAP works in W7P Series.

I know that I need some way of sending credentials over but the win 7 API does not seem to let you.
**ServiceReferences.ClientConfig**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="ViewsSoap" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered">
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly"/>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://my.secureconnection.com/_vti_bin/views.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ViewsSoap"
                contract="SharePointListService.ViewsSoap" name="ViewsSoap"  />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**This is my maincode page:**

```
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait | SupportedPageOrientation.Landscape;
            try
            {
                Uri serviceUri = new Uri("https://my.secureconnection.com" + SERVICE_LISTS_URL);
                BasicHttpBinding binding;
                if (serviceUri.Scheme == "https")
                {
                    binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
                }
                else
                {
                    binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
                }
                EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(serviceUri);
                ListsSoapClient listSoapClient = new ListsSoapClient(binding, endpoint);


                NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential("administrator", "iSynergy1", "server001");
                //listSoapClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Identification;
                //listSoapClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = creds;

                listSoapClient.GetListCollectionCompleted += new EventHandler<GetListCollectionCompletedEventArgs>(listSoapClient_GetListCollectionCompleted);
                listSoapClient.GetListCollectionAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                handleException("Failed to get list collection", exception);
            }
        }
        #region ShowExceptionDetail Property
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowExceptionDetailDependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ShowExceptionDetail",typeof(bool),typeof(Page),new PropertyMetadata(true));
        public bool ShowExceptionDetail
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowExceptionDetailDependencyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ShowExceptionDetailDependencyProperty, value); }
        }
        #endregion
        private void handleException(string context, Exception exception)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
            {
                bool showExceptionDetail = this.ShowExceptionDetail;

                string message = "";

                Exception next = exception;
                do
                {
                    if (message.Length > 0) { message += ";" + Environment.NewLine; }
                    if (next.Message == null || next.Message.Length == 0) { message += next.GetType().FullName; }
                    else { message += next.Message; }
                    if (showExceptionDetail)
                    {
                        if (next.Data.Count > 0)
                        {
                            bool first = true;
                            message += " {";
                            foreach (string key in next.Data.Keys)
                            {
                                if (first) { first = false; }
                                else { message += ", "; }
                                message += key + "=\"" + next.Data[key] + "\"";
                            }
                            message += "}";
                        }
                        if (next.InnerException != next)
                        {
                            next = next.InnerException;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    next = null;
                }
                while (next != null);
                MessageBox.Show(message, context, MessageBoxButton.OK);
            });
        }

        private const string SERVICE_LISTS_URL = "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
        void listSoapClient_GetListCollectionCompleted(object sender, GetListCollectionCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try { myList.Text = e.Result.ToString(); }
            catch (Exception exception) { handleException("Failed to get list collection", exception); }
        }
    }
```

When I run this and it gets to the "ListsSoapClient" part, it breaks.  If you dig down into the error output it says access is denied.  I have tried various methods of sending credentials but none seem to work.  "ClientCredentials.Windows" is not supported and ClientCredentials.UsersName.Username is read only.

Comment: Over at the MSDN forums I got a few replies with people having similar issues.  It looks like it is a bug in the current SDK.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/43a84dff-9447-4e95-8040-8a5447514fa0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has confirmed that NTLM is not supported yet in the SDK. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/43a84dff-9447-4e95-8040-8a5447514fa0

---

**UPDATE**

Looks like someone found a workaround http://zetitle.wordpress.com/2010/03/30/wp7-connecting-to-web-services-that-uses-authentication/